# Swap all youtube urls to embed via preg_replace()

Tags: php, preg-replace

Hello I'm trying to convert youtube links into embed code.

this is what I have:

```
<?php

$text = $post->text;

     $search = '#<a(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*$#x';
     $replace = '<center><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>';
     $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);


echo $text;
?>
```

It works for one link. However if I add two, it will only swap the last occurrence. What do I have to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not handling the end of the string properly. Remove the `$`, and replace it with the closing tag `</a>`. this will fix it.

```
 $search = '#<a(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*<\/a>#x';
 $replace = '<center><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>';
 $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed it in all those regex symbols.

Comment: Sure, and you're missing as well the meaning of greedy in the regex domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `preg_replace($search, $replace, $text, -1);`

I know it's the default but who knows...

**EDIT** Try that if not working ;

```
do{
    $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text, -1, $Count);
}
while($Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a regular expresion more efficient: http://pregcopy.com/exp/26, tralate this to PHP: (add "s" modifier)

```
<?php

$text = $post->text;

     $search = '#<a (?:.*?)href=["\\\']http[s]?:\/\/(?:[^\.]+\.)*youtube\.com\/(?:v\/|watch\?(?:.*?\&)?v=|embed\/)([\w\-\_]+)["\\\']#ixs';
     $replace = '<center><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>';

     $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);


echo $text;
?>
```

Test it

Answer (score 0):

**There are two types of youtube link for one video:**

Example:

```
$link1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVcpJZJ60Ao';
$link2 = 'https://www.youtu.be/NVcpJZJ60Ao';
```

**This function handles both:**

```
function getYoutubeEmbedUrl($url)
{
     $shortUrlRegex = '/youtu.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\??/i';
$longUrlRegex = '/youtube.com\/((?:embed)|(?:watch))((?:\?v\=)|(?:\/))([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/i';

    if (preg_match($longUrlRegex, $url, $matches)) {
        $youtube_id = $matches[count($matches) - 1];
    }

    if (preg_match($shortUrlRegex, $url, $matches)) {
        $youtube_id = $matches[count($matches) - 1];
    }
    return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $youtube_id ;
}
```

The output of $link1 or $link2 would be the same :

```
 $output1 = getYoutubeEmbedUrl($link1);
 $output2 = getYoutubeEmbedUrl($link2);
 // output for both:  https://www.youtube.com/embed/NVcpJZJ60Ao
```

Now you can use the output in iframe!

Comment: @Toto thanks for the suggestion, I have copied this regex from a website and have no idea  what `$matches[count($matches) - 1]` mean!! But I think It could be like this: `$matches[0]` not this: `$matches[-1]`  right?  because we will have one match and it will be the first one in `$matches`  array.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed with other language, where `$matches[-1]` stands for the last index, in PHP we have to use `end($matches)`. Here we have 3 elements in the array. Please, don't copy/paste code from external site without testing it. At least give the reference.