# change youtube url to embed url in php

Tags: php, regex, youtube, preg-replace

I found this code ([Swap all youtube urls to embed via preg_replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435645/swap-all-youtube-urls-to-embed-via-preg-replace)) to swap youtube urls (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfDQ92vOfdc, or http://www.youtube.com/v/CfDQ92vOfdc) into youtube embed urls (http://www.youtube.com/embed/CfDQ92vOfdc) but it doesn't seem to be working? Any ideas? I don't know much about regular expression.

Here's the code:

```
$string     = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfDQ92vOfdc';
$search     = '#<a (?:.*?)href=["\\\']http[s]?:\/\/(?:[^\.]+\.)*youtube\.com\/(?:v\/|watch\?(?:.*?\&)?v=|embed\/)([\w\-\_]+)["\\\']#ixs';
$replace    = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';
$url        = preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

but it's still displaying as:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfDQ92vOfdc
```

instead of:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/CfDQ92vOfdc
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its looking for an anchor tag, not just a URL. you string should be `<a href="...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Either change**

`$string     = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfDQ92vOfdc';`

to

`$string     = '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfDQ92vOfdc" ></a>';`

**OR**

```
$search     = '#<a (?:.*?)href=["\\\']http[s]?:\/\/(?:[^\.]+\.)*youtube\.com\/(?:v\/|watch\?(?:.*?\&)?v=|embed\/)([\w\-\_]+)["\\\']#ixs';
```

to

```
$search     = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
```

Comment: That worked great for me, as I don't need the a tag. Thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

One problem is that your expression is expecting a-href tags around the address.
Another issue is that your $replace string is using single-quotes which will not parse $2.

This simpler expression should work:

```
$string     = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfDQ92vOfdc';
$search     = '/youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/smi';
$replace    = "youtube.com/embed/$1";    
$url = preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
echo $url;
```

Comment: very cool; currently using a modified version of this in production. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is anyone who is still looking for a better straight up solution ,
here it is I just played with your code until it gave me an easy solution.

```
$string     = $content;
```

`$search     = '/www.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/smi';`

`$replace    = "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://youtube.com/embed/$1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
";

$content = preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);`

NOTE: to choose how you want the links to be processed just edit the `$search` part,
if you will be processing from www.youtube.com it will be
    `$search     = '/www.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/smi';`

else if you want it to process just youtube.com links just remove the `www.
$search   = '/youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/smi';`

Answer (score 0):

here is a function i wrote that you echo out the result:

```
function youtube_url_to_embed($youtube_url) {
    $search = '/youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/smi';
    $replace = "youtube.com/embed/$1";
    $embed_url = preg_replace($search,$replace,$youtube_url);
    return $embed_url;
}
```