# Integrate this regex code into existing php code

Tags: javascript, php, regex, video, youtube

I'm using the code below to output a video embed for the latest video:

```
$args = array( 
    'numberposts' => '1', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-video'
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'dt_video',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
    )
);
$latest_video = wp_get_recent_posts($args); // Get latest video in 'video' post format
$latest_video_id = $latest_video['0']['ID']; // Get latest video ID
$video_url = htmlspecialchars(get_post_meta($latest_video_id, 'dt_video', true));
echo '<iframe width="180" height="101" src="'.$video_url.'?rel=0&output=embed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

The URL outputs fine in the HTML, but the video doesn't show and I get the following error in the console:

`Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4X2hQC32NA&feature=g-all-u&context=G258729eFAAAAAAAAHAA?rel=0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Through some searching, I found that this is because the format of the videos is incorrect.

The URL in the error above should be formatted like this: `www.youtube.com/embed/l4X2hQC32NA?rel=0`

So, I [found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435645/swap-all-youtube-urls-to-embed-via-preg-replace) to dynamically change the format with the code below:

```
$text = $post->text;
    $search = '#<a(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*<\/a>#x';
    $replace = '<iframe width="180" height="101" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
echo $text;
```

However, I am not sure how I can implement that into the original code so I can change the format of the outputted URL. Can someone show me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$video_url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4X2hQC32NA&feature=g-all-u&context=G258729eFAAAAAAAAHAA?rel=0";
$search  = '#(?:href="https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*$#x';
$replace = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1";
preg_match_all($search, $video_url, $matches);
$embedded_video_url = preg_replace($search, $replace, $video_url) ;
echo '<iframe width="180" height="101" src="'.$embedded_video_url.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Simply use your own `$video_url`

Comment: Thank you. I had to get rid of `http://` in the third line because it was adding it unnecessarily like this: `http://http//www.youtube.com/embed/l4X2hQC32NA` But now it's working.